# I am getting closure issue on loop, still i use the separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my loop, i am trying to add the `class` name to element. to avoid `closure` issue, i am keeping separate function.

But still my issue not fixed.

i am finding the class name in object like this:

```
<button class="sidebar1 sidebar2 sidebar3 sidebar4 sidebar5">Click</button>
```

here is my js:

```
var ob = {};

var catcheBars = {};
var sidebar = $('div.sidebar');
var catchedBar = sidebar;


for(i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if(!ob.hasOwnProperty(i+'page')) {
        ob[i+'page'] = catchedBar;
    }
    var x = i;
    var x = function (x) {
        $(ob[x+'page']).find('button').addClass('sidebar'+x);
    }(x)


}


$("#sideBar").html(ob['1page']);
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/0an0ypwu/2/)

Comment: I think this is an X/Y problem, you're asking why the loop doesn't work, but what you really want is to `clone()` the element, not just pass the same reference around.

Comment: @Teemu, this is not the whole functionality, this one part of function.

Comment: What do you want `ob` to contain?

Comment: i require to keep copies of sidebar with unique ids. and i would like to add unique event to each of button

Comment: So, you just want to add a unique class to each button so that they can have different events bound to them?

Comment: yes, exactly. and in the document, on click i would like to copy the document text to unique side bar too..

Comment: You are over-complicating this problem just a bit.  Check my answer, I tried to simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated like this, it works for me

```
var ob = {};

var catcheBars = {};
var sidebar = $('div.sidebar');

for(i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if(!ob.hasOwnProperty(i+'page')) {
        ob[i+'page'] = sidebar.clone(false);
    }
    var x = function (x) {
        $(ob[x+'page']).addClass('sideBar'+x);
    }(i);
}

sidebar.empty();
$("#sideBar").html(ob['1page']);


console.log(ob);
```

Thanks to everyone!
[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/0an0ypwu/3/)

Comment: There is no reason to have to do `function (x){}(i)` here.  The issue that is trying to solve is when there is a callback function that is called *later*, after the loop finishes.  You can just do `$(ob[i+'page']).addClass('sideBar'+i);` here.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `var catchedBar = sidebar;` you are actually making `catchedBar` a *reference* to the `sidebar` object.  Then in your loop, when you do `ob[i+'page'] = catchedBar;`, you are now making *another* reference.

When you do `.addClass()` on `$(ob[x+'page'])`, you are adding the class to *everything* in the collection since `ob[x+'page']` contains a reference to the `$('div.sidebar')` collection.

This code is a little too complicated for what you are trying to achieve.  It can be simplified using jQuery's `.each` method:

```
$('div.sidebar').each(function(i, v){
    $(v).find('button').addClass('sidebar'+i);
});
```

Note: I wasn't 100% sure what you were trying to do.

UPDATE: After seeing your comments, I think all you need to do is this:

```
$('div.sidebar button').click(function(){
    $("#sideBar").html($(this).text());
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xtcxv8hd/